# How can I rotate the autpct in a pie plot if labels are already rotated?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, plot-annotations

I plotted a pie chart and rotate the labels:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = { 'T1': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2],
         'T2':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
               'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
               'C', 'C', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'C',
              'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['T1']=df['T1'].astype(str)
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
values2=df['T2'].value_counts().sort_index()
pie1=ax.pie(values2, radius=1.3, autopct='%1.1f%%', labeldistance=0.4,   
       labels=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], rotatelabels=True, startangle=223.5, wedgeprops=dict(width=1, edgecolor='w'));
for tx in pie1[1]:
    rot = tx.get_rotation()
    tx.set_rotation(rot+90+(1-rot//180)*180)
hole = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.5, facecolor='white')
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(hole)
plt.show()
```

[image: example pie chart]

I can't use startangle a 2nd time to rotate the percentages. How can I do this to give the pie chart a better look?

Now I tried to use:

```
for tx in pie1[2]:
    rotate = tx.get_rotation()
    tx.set_rotation(rotate+90+(1-rotate//180)*180)
```

Because I understood that the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAPYM.jpg) in pie[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAPYM.jpg) refers to the autopct (am I right?). But then the percentages are rotated in a different way than the labels. Has anyone an idea why?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [`pie`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) returns a tuple of lists :

> **patches** : *list*
> A sequence of `matplotlib.patches.Wedge` instances
>
> **texts** : *list*
> A list of the label `Text` instances.
>
> **autotexts** : *list*
> A list of `Text` instances for the numeric labels. This
> will only be returned ..

So you can unpack it and rotate the *labels/percentages* in `//` :

```
p, t, a = ax.pie(
    values2, radius=1.3, autopct='%1.1f%%', labeldistance=0.4,
    labels=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], rotatelabels=True, startangle=223.5,
    wedgeprops=dict(width=1, edgecolor='w')
)

for tx, pc in zip(t, a):
    rot = tx.get_rotation()
    tx.set_rotation(rot+90+(1-rot//180)*180)
    pc.set_rotation(tx.get_rotation())
```

Output :

[image]